# Checkbox state isn't being recorded with jQuery ajax to Django View

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, django-forms, django-views

I've looked everywhere and tried everything I know how to do.

The problem is, when I click a checkbox, it's not being saved.

Right now I can see in my Post that the right question is added and then the right value is being added. But nothing is saved on the backend. I think this has everything to do with my View and not my JS so I'll start with the save form view and include the AJAX post below that.

Also, when I look at the post responses I'm seeing 302, not 200 as I'd expect. Is that a jQuery thing?

One thing to note, I'm going through old code from a different developer, so it's possible I'm missing something.

Lemme know if you have suggestions.

The render method for the view includes this:

```
if request.method == 'POST' and all_valid_forms(forms):
        for form in forms:
            for (key, value) in form.cleaned_data.items():
                try:
                    (name, question_id) = key.split('.', 1)
                except ValueError:
                    continue
                # Get question object
                question = QuestionItem.objects.get(pk=question_id)
                # Save to QuestionLog
                QuestionLog.objects.create(user=request.user,
                                           question=question,
                                           value=value)
        return redirect('render_view', module_id,
                        view_id)
```

The ajax is pretty simple

```
$('#fs').on('click', $(this), function () {
    var next_url = $('#fs').attr('data-link');

    $('.checkbox input').each(function(index) {
        if($(this).is(':checked')) {
            // console.log("I'm checked");
            $(this).attr('value', 'True');
        } else {
            $(this).attr('value', 'False');
        }
    });

    var content = $('form#t-cont').serialize();
    // console.log(next_url);
    console.log(content);
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        data: content,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(content);
            console.log('Saved!');
            //window.location = next_url;
        },
        error: function() {
            console.log('Not saved');
        }
    });
    //event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: You're getting a 302 because you explicitly return a redirect, which is 302. Note that is an odd thing to do in an Ajax handler.

Comment: Are you sure you are going through the loop? 302 means there is a redirection, it can be your "return redirect" or something else (for instance, you are not logged in). If you are going through the loop, check if there is a custom save method for the QuestionLog model with a try/except block in it, which could fail silently.